# Method cannot be marked @objc because its result type cannot be represented in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, optional-parameters, objective-c-runtime

am exposing swift API's in Objective-C and the Objective-C runtime.

When i add "@objc" before the function throws an error "Method cannot be marked @objc because its result type cannot be represented in Objective-C"

My code is here

```
@objc public static func logIn(_ userId: String) -> User? { }
```

User is optional struct. how to solve this.

Comment: Show `class` declaration code for this function (`class` for this function)

Comment: public final class Manager : NSObject { }

Comment: add your code of `User`

Comment: User is a struct not the class.

Comment: @SriMa target/selector is not possible with swift Struct, if you are using one i suggest you call the selector from any NSObject class

Comment: can you post the struct code?

Answer (score 11):

The key bit of information is this:

> User is optional struct

If `User` is a struct, then it can't be represented in Objective-C, just the same as a Swift class that doesn't inherit from `NSObject`.

In order for the method `logIn(_:)` to be able to be marked `@objc`, then every type referenced in the method declaration has to be representable in Objective-C. You're getting the error message because `User` isn't.

To fix it, you're either going to have to change the declaration of `User` from this:

```
struct User {
    // ...
}
```

...to this:

```
class User: NSObject {
    // ...
}
```

...or redesign `logIn(_:)` so that it doesn't return a `User`.

---

You can find more information about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28567380/how-to-pass-a-swift-struct-as-parameter-to-an-objective-c-method). In particular, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28953007/6073823) offers the following potential solution:

> The best thing i found was to wrap in a Box class
>
> ```
> public class Box<T>: NSObject {
>     let unbox: T
>     init(_ value: T) {
>         self.unbox = value
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: @SriMa Please look more closely at my code sample. You have to not only add inheritance from `NSObject` but also change it from a `struct` to a `class`

Comment: @SriMa You are repeatedly replying to people's answers by saying "User is a struct not the class". You need to change it from a `struct` to a `class`; this is the essence of most of the answers.

Comment: I want to keep the User struct. I don't want to be make it as class.

Comment: In that case, please note the end of my answer, where I say "or redesign `logIn(_:)` so that it doesn't return a `User`." It is not possible to do what you are asking; `struct`s cannot be represented in Objective-C.

Comment: @SriMa I've edited my answer to include another potential solution from a different StackOverflow answer.

Comment: I don't want to make it as class. As per my requirement it should be struct. Any work around for that.. ?

Comment: @SriMa Yes, that's in the edit I made to my question. You can use the `Box` class defined at the bottom, and use that to wrap `User`. I'll warn you, though, your options are quite limited if you want to keep `User` as a struct, and you might run into additional problems down the line.

Comment: Can you help me to explain with an example.. ?

Comment: I don't think the `Box` solution will work, because generic classes are not visible to Objective-C.

Answer (score 3):

Change the definition of your class as below

```
class User: NSObject {

}
```

In this way this class will be available in Objective-C

Answer (score 0):

Your class or protocol, must be inherited (extended) by `NSObject` or anyother class in its hierarchy, containing your code (function) with `@objc` notation.

Example:

```
class TestClass {
    public static func logIn(_ userId: String) -> User? { }
}
```

To use/declare `@objc` with this function, class must extend `NSObject` (or any other class in its hierarchy)

```
class TestClass {
    @objc public static func logIn(_ userId: String) -> User? { }
}
```

#### Update:

`struct` may not work with optional value in Objective-C, as a work around, you should change `User` from `struct` to `class`

Try following code and see:

```
public class User : NSObject {
    // Your code
}

public final class Manager : NSObject {

    @objc public static func logIn(_ userId: String) -> User? {
        return nil
    }
}
```

Here is snapshot with editor

[image]

Comment: User is struct not the class.

Comment: @SriMa `struct` may not work with optional value in Objective-C, as a work around, you should change `User` from `struct` to `class`

Answer (score -1):

Only an NSObject-derived class type can be seen by Objective-C. Use:

```
class User : NSObject {
```

}